# What is the "Fx Functions" in Azure applications Insights? How can you add one?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

Recently, I've been working with application insights and building up my queries and understanding. One of the features that I would expect is to define functions outside of the scope of a particular kusto script/query with the intention that the function can be reused from other scripts/queries.

[image: Application Insights Log Analytics]

When I started working with it, I had noticed a menu item under the sources that was labeled `fx functions` and had assumed that this is where I could eventually add my functions. Initially, I saw no UI path to create one and I thought this was due to authorization policies. As I'm now much more comfortable with the Kusto language, I want to break my big scripts into smaller ones but I can't.

I've checked with a private account, where I'm full owner, if I could add one but there no UI path as well. I spoke with our Azure configurators and he as an owner can't find a UI path as well. This doesn't seem to be a result of limited authorization. I've google this and I can't find anything. I've the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/) and there is not mention.

Anyone knows what this is and if it represents a custom functions library how can it be modified? How would you reference it?

## Update 1

From an answer provided by @ivan-yang, it seems that I missed this when trying out with my personal account. Apparently, you can save a script as

- A query

  - Private
  - Shared
- A function

When saving as a function, the system creates a reference in the shared queries but with a different icon.

[image: a function and a shared query]

Comment: A more thorough explanation based on this Q&A, is available [here](https://sarafian.github.io/azure/2019/07/25/kusto-fx-functions-application-insights-logs-analytics.html) as well

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Correction, I can update the function. When a function and a shared query exist with the same name, then there is a problem. Once I renamed the shared query to something else, I could overwrite the function.

---

In the application insights -> Logs, in the editor field, you can write a query, then click save -> in the popup window, provide a name like f1, then save as Function. Then you can see the the new function f1 in the "fx Functions":

[image]

And as per my test, if you define a custom function and save it, there is no chance to modify it.

Regarding how to reference it, you can use the function like requests / traces, like using union / filter etc.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that when trying with my private account. In essence it shows up in the shared queries with an `fx` icon. You can delete but you can't replace. To replace you need to first delete and then save over. The difference with a query is that a query can't be referenced by other query scripts and the function can. 

In the organization's account, this is hidden. We don't even see the options for save as function or shared query.

Comment: Correction, I can update the function. When a function and a shared query exist with the same name, then there is a problem. Once I renamed the shared query to something else, I could overwrite the function.

Comment: @AlexSarafian, thanks for your sharing. I added your comment to my post, and if the answer is helpful, could you please help mark it as answer? Thanks.